# Strong type inequality $(p,q)$ implies weak type inequality $(p,q)$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Recall that 
a weak type $(p,q)$ is when you have a $C>0$ such that 
$\mathrm{measure}(|T_f(x)|> \alpha)\leq \frac{c ||f||^q_{L^p}}{\alpha^q}$.

Also, we have a strong type $(p,q)$ if $\Vert T_f\Vert_{L^q} \leq c \Vert f\Vert_{L^p}$

I have seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671590/what-does-a-weak-type-inequality-mean), in the comment section,that a strong type inequality $(p,p)$ implies a weak type inequality $(p,p)$.
Why is this the case?
Does it also hold for $(p,q)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathrm{measure}(|T_f(x)|> \alpha)&=\int_{|T_f(x)|> \alpha}1\\
&\le\int_{|T_f(x)|> \alpha}\left(\frac{|T_f(x)|}{\alpha}\right)^q\\
&\le \frac{1}{\alpha^q}\int|T_f(x)|^q\\
&\le \frac{1}{\alpha^q}\,c\,\|f\|_{L^p}^q.
\end{align}